# Ajuste dinamico de alto de un vLayout

Tags: java, smartgwt

Tengo un problema utilizando GWT el problema general es que estoy insertando un recurso mediante la URL en un HTMLFlow donde le doy la url del recurso

```
    htmlPage = new HTMLFlow();    
    htmlPage.setContentsURL(urlPage);

    ....

    vLayout panel = new VLayout();
    panel.add(htmlPage);
```

El problema de esto es que si el objeto htmlPage no le doy el alto, cuando se carga el contenido de la URL, no se visualiza dicho contenido.

la idea es que el vLayout de ajuste automáticamente al alto del contenido dentro de htmlPage.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas meter el *HTMLFlow* dentro del *vLayout* por algo? Si no es necesario la solución es tan facil como hacer lo siguiente y olvidarte del *vLayout*.

```
htmlPage = new HTMLFlow();    
htmlPage.setContentsURL(urlPage);
htmlPage.show();
```

Si necesitas el vLayout porque despues vas a añadir mas widgets aparte de este HTMLFlow tendrás que tener encuenta lo siguiente:

> NOTE: Since the size of an HTMLFlow component is determined by its
>   HTML contents, this component will draw at varying sizes if given
>   content of varying size. When using HTMLFlow components within a
>   Layout, consider what will happen if the HTMLFlow renders at various
>   sizes. An HTMLFlow which can expand should be placed in a container
>   where other components can render smaller, where the container is
>   allowed to scroll, or where there is padding to expand into.
>   [Documentacion HTMLFlow](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/HTMLFlow.html)

La solución más comoda sería que le digas al vLayout lo que tiene que medir, le metas el HTMLFlow y le permitas al vLayout scrollear si el contenido se hace demasiado grande.

Algo así:

```
htmlPage = new HTMLFlow();    
htmlPage.setContentsURL(urlPage);
vLayout panel = new VLayout();
panel.setHeight("100%");
panel.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
panel.add(htmlPage);
panel.show();
```

Comment: Trate tambiend e realizar eso, pero no me sirvio par alo que neceitaba. otra cosa es que el contenido que estaba introduciendo en el HTML Flow era como aplicación, esto me impedia dejar el alto automatico. Además de que no apareciera el scroll.
Pero Gracias por responder :)